Continuity of point to set mapping
For the point-to-set map $\Omega(x): X \rightrightarrows Y$ let
\begin{equation}
    v(x) \equiv \sup_{y \in \Omega(x)} f(x,y),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    f: X \times Y \rightarrow [-\infty +\infty],
\end{equation}
and  let the point-to-set map
\begin{equation}
    M(x) = \{ y \in \Omega(x) ~ | ~ v(x) \leq f(x,y) \}.
\end{equation}
describe the solution set of the supremal value function $v$.
I would like to understand the proof of the following:  If  $\Omega$ is continuous at $\bar{x}$, $f$ is continuous on $\bar{x} \times \Omega(\bar{x})$, $M$ is nonemtpy and uniformly compact near $\bar{x}$ and $M(\bar{x})$ is single-valued. Then $M$ is continuous at $\bar{x}$.
It is already shown that $M$ is closed at $\bar{x}$. Thus, it remains to show that $M$ is open.
Therefore, I assume that $x^k \rightarrow \bar{x}$ with $\bar{y} \in M(\bar{x})$. By contradiction, assume that $y^k \in M(x^k)$ but there is an open neighborhood of $\bar{y}$, say $B$ such thatt $y^k \notin B$ for infinitely many $k$.
Now the reasoning in the proof goes as follows: Since $M$ is uniformly compact, $\{y^k\}$ must have a cluster point $\hat{y} \notin B$ (why?). But $M$ is closed at $\bar{x}$, thus we have the contradiction that $\hat{y} = \bar{y}$ (why?).
Edit: I now understand how closedness is used: Since $y^k$ has a cluster point $\hat{y}$, there exists a subsequence $y^k_j$ such that $y^k_j \rightarrow \hat{y}$. However, because $M$ is closed at $\bar{x}$, we have that $\hat{y} \in M(\bar{x})$. Since $M(\bar{x})$ is single valued by assumption, we conclude $\hat{y} = \bar{y}$. Thus such a $B$ cannot exist.
However, I still don't understand how uniform compactness is used.
Why does there exist a cluster point?

You refer to "$S(x)$" a couple times without defining it. Is it supposed to be "$\Omega(x)$"?

Yes, it's $\Omega(x)$.

Let $N$ be a neigbhorhood of $\bar x$ such that $\text{cl}(\Omega(N))$ is compact, where $\Omega(N) := \bigcup_{x\in N} \Omega(x)$. Because the sequence $x_k \to \bar x$, it is eventually inside $N$, and therefore the sequence $\{y_k\}_k$ is eventually in $\Omega(N) \subseteq \text{cl}(\Omega(N))$. Since $B$ is an open neighborhood, the intersection of $\text{cl}(\Omega(N))$ with $X\setminus B$ is also compact, and by the assumption must contain an infinite subsequence of $\{y_k\}_k$. Any sequence in a compact set has at least one convergent subsequence $\{y_{k_j}\}_j$ which converges to a point $\bar y$ in the set, an therefore not in $B$.
